# Xargs With Multiple Argument Substitutions - Use environment variable argument after sh -c '...'

Tags: quoting, xargs, parameter

This is my command:

```
find $1 -name "*.html"  | sort -n | xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo "Dumping file: "{} >> "$2"; w3m {} >> "$2" 2>&1'
```

where:

$1 is the path where I will look for files with the extension .html

$2 is the file where I want to log the information (Dumping the file: *html and the information contained in this html file)

The problem is that $2 is not interpreted. May be because this variable is between '...'
I tried with double quotes but then the command is not working.

Does anybody know how to pass the information of $2 in my command line?

Comment: Never embed  `{}` in the code. What if there's a file called `$(reboot).html`? See Rakesh' answer for how to do it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find "$1" -name "*.html" -print0 | sort -zn | xargs -r -0 -n 1 sh -c '
   echo "Dumping file: $2" >> "$1"; w3m "$2" >> "$1" 2>&1
' sh "$2"
```

One more optimization can be:

```
find "$1" -name "*.html" -print0 | sort -zn | xargs -r -0 -n 1 sh -c '
   exec 1>> "$1" 2>&1
   echo "Dumping file: $2"
   w3m "$2"
' sh "$2"
```

since both the commands `echo` and `w3m` are doing the same things with their file descriptors 1 and 2, so it's better we do it in one place at the beginning.

You can also avoid running one `sh` per file with:

```
find "$1" -name "*.html" -print0 | sort -zn | xargs -r -0 sh -c '
   out=$1; shift
   for file do
     echo "Dumping file: $file"
     w3m "$file"
   done >> "$out" 2>&1
' sh "$2"
```

Comment: Thanks to Stephane Chazleas for pointing out the use of `-print0` in the `find` output` section for the rest of the code to be meaningful.

Comment: Thanks! I just don't understand what the last command do 'sh "$2"'. Does it dump the information in the file I want?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks for the upgrade. I noticed a minor semicolon is missing after the `for file` construct.

Comment: @VictorDoors That 'sh' in the first place of the argument list functions as the "$0" of the `sh -c '...' $0 $1 $2 ...` construct. The `$2` is as the $1 is the name of the log file and will in reality be the first argument. The invisible space is the place for the $2 and shall be filled in by `xargs` via it's option `-n 1` , with the options being delimited by the `\0` character.

Comment: `for file do` is more portable than `for file; do`. The Bourne shell doesn't support `for file; do`. Before the 2016 edition of POSIX, `for file; do` was not standard.

Comment: @RakeshSharma In the last optimization there is not option "-n 1". So I think that the shift command must do something similar i.e: In the first iteration shift changes the input argument "$3" that will be the new "$2".
However the for loop gets the old "$2" in the variable "file". 
Is my guess correct?
Thanks.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I thought that the Bourne shell needed a literal newline after the file and before the do (atleast Sun/Solaris bourne did require a hard newline). Thanks for the updates.

Comment: @VictorDoors When we DONOT use `-n 1` in effect we are instructing `xargs` to supply as many arguments to the calling program (in this case it is the sh -c '...'). Thus we have the scenario: `sh -c '...' sh "$2" htmlA htmlB htmlC ... wherein $0 <= sh, $1 <= "$2", $2 <= htmlA, $3 <= htmlB, ... Due to the shift command, the `out` variable gets the name of the logfile (top level "$2") which then gets shifted out. What's left are the names of the html files coming from find+sort. These are then looped over using the for file do...done loop. Hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove them from single quotes:

```
... sh -c 'echo "Dumping file: "{} >> '"$2"'; w3m {} >> '"$2"' 2>&1'
```

The shell will glue everything together.

Answer (score 0):

Some ways to work around the quoting would be to pass the variables to the inner `sh` as arguments:

```
log=$2
... | xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo "Dumping file: $1" >> "$2"; w3m {} >> "$2" 2>&1' sh {} "$log"
```

or just `export` the relevant variables so you refer to them by name

```
export log=$2
... | xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo "Dumping file: $1" >> "$log"; w3m {} >> "$log" 2>&1' sh {}
```

Though note that plain `find` and `xargs -L` might work badly if you have weird filenames: newlines obviously, and `-L` treats trailing whitespace specially.